# Debugging Zos cobol with RDz

Tags: debugging, cobol, zos

My intetion is to debug the called cobol program aswel.
But not sure how to keep a break point to go inside the called cobol program.
At the moment i am able to debugg the main cobol program and control just goes over the called copbol program.Thanks

Comment: In order to help you, we need to know more about the environment. Is it cobol on a Mainframe?

Comment: yes it is cobol on mainframe.

Comment: I just realized you had it in the title, sry for the unnecessary question... Also, now I see that you are using the Eclipse based IDE, not a standard ISPF solution.

Comment: Is it a CICS application, or a batch program?

Comment: It would have been nice to answer our questions or let us know how you solved the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Considering that it is Cobol on a Mainframe and that you already accessed the debugger, I guess the issue is with the compilation of the called program.

Usually, programs that are called by a program in debugger are jumped over (they run, but you can't see code or control them) if you forget to compile the called program with debugger option.

The same way you compiled your program with DEBUG option, you can compile the called program. This usually is done with a 'D' option at the compilation screen.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: its cics application. have compiled both caller and called pgm with same compiler options. but no luck..

Comment: Does your compile proc has these COBOL comile options? SOURCE, LIST, XREF, MAP, LIB

Comment: Also, it may be that you did not put the called program under debug control. Here I am not sure what is your company using, it may be CADP, DTCN , etc. Where you put the main program under debug control, there you may have to specify the called programs you want to debug as well.

Comment: One more thing. After you compiled the called program with debug option, you have to tell CICS that the program changed. CEMT SET PROG(prg_name) NEWCOPY (this is the most common way to do it). It may be that RDz is doing this automatically, you should check.

Comment: sorry for confusing.. it is batch cobol. no cics.

Comment: Could you describe the steps you did before opening Debug Perspective?  Also are you using CADP to setup the CICS side? We need way more information to help with this issue. It would help if you could desribe all the steps taken.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building the called subprogram in the same RD/z project?  That can make a difference.  Otherwise, you will need to use the mainframe side of things to point your debug info back at your workstaions IP address either via the LE TEST() parameter on the parm string or by linking in a custom CEEINIT to specify those parms.